# Narrow down pkl depedencies

Tags: python, dependencies, requirements.txt, cloudpickle

I am using cloudpickle.load and sys.modules to narrow down the dependencies for requirements.txt of the pickle. However, the dependencies generated are not the same across environments. When I run the code in a Conda environment, I observe sys.modules containing dependencies that were not part of the pickle file, such as NumPy. Is there any way to fix the behavior of the sys.modules cache across environments?

```
def get_currently_used_packages():
    """Placeholder docstring"""
    all_installed_packages = get_all_installed_packages() # from pip 
    package_to_file_names = map_package_names_to_files([x["name"] for x in all_installed_packages])

    currently_used_files = {
        Path(m.__file__)
        for m in sys.modules.values()
        if inspect.ismodule(m) and hasattr(m, "__file__") and m.__file__
    }

    currently_used_packages = set()
    for file in currently_used_files:
        for package in package_to_file_names:
            if file in package_to_file_names[package]:
                #logger.info(f"Capturing package -- {package}")
                currently_used_packages.add(package)
    return currently_used_packages, currently_used_files

with open(pkl_path, mode="rb") as file:
    cloudpickle.load(file)

get_currently_used_packages() # using to generate requirements.txt
```